# How to word wrap <ul><li><div><a></a></div></li></ul>

Tags: css, word-wrap, html-lists

How would I be able to have word wrap when text in `<a>` is way too long? I want the `<li>` to expand to the word wrap using CSS.

Comment: Can you post a code sample with the sample text?

Comment: Please post an example - you could use jsbin.com to show us what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [`word-wrap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#word-wrap) property?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word;">
            <a></a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're after here, but the [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#wrapping) `text-wrap` or `word-wrap` might do it.

You could also try setting a width on the `<li>`. That would force the text inside it to a certain width.

Finally, if the text does not contain spaces/wrappable chars, perhaps [`<wbr>`](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linepar/_WBR.html) [might work](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-wbr-element)